# Oracle query speed drastically changes with new connections

Tags: oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance, toad

I have a db query with 3 joins on 2 tables (2 self joins) and order by clause at the end. Database server is on another db server, Oracle11g. We have a tool that runs this query internally that is slow(11 hours instead of 1 hour at max).

I grabbed this query from logs and run it in Toad 11.5, it takes 10 seconds at first (in the morning - db untouched over night). Then I go to the db server and run the tool, kill it or let it finish, then I come back to Toad and run this query, it takes about 2-3 hours to finish, same query without any changes.

Please  help me trouble shoot this strange behavior. Also, when the query is taking 10 secs, on removal of order by , it takes about 500 mili seconds if this information helps in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

TOAD fooled you. It did return first 500 (or what) rows, but not the whole data set. Try to go to the end of data set (Ctrl + End), you'll see how much it takes (read: *ages*).

Two options I can think of:

- use `driving_site` hint, which will force execution on the database server, not computer you're currently connected to
- move the procedure to the database server itself and call it from your local connection

Comment: no procedures, only a select statement. Is there a way to disable this caching kind of behavior in toad?  Also, why does it not behave the same way after running the tool ? Toad's behavior should remain unaltered

Comment: Which TOAD version do you use? See whether "Options" in your version offer "OCI Array Buffer Size"; if so, see what it can be set to. I know it doesn't exist in 12.5, but is (as Google says) back in 12.7.

Comment: Toad 11.5 .I read more on OCI Buffer size, I have 2.5 million records being returned. I can't set Buffer Size of toad to that value (impractical, that big buffer would be allocated on every fetch). I just need to figure out how  much time db needs to run the given query , don't even need to view data. Please suggest if there is any other way.

Comment: You have a query; suppose it looks like `select many_columns from many_tables where some_conditions`. In order to force TOAD to fetch them all, select count from it, e.g. `select count(*) from (select many_columns from many_tables where some_conditions)`, i.e. make your query *source* for the count.